# SQL get the largest primary key where another field is the largest

Tags: sql, grouping, max

Here is a sample data set.

```
shareId mode    shareLevel  targetId    targetItemId
26          1   5           0           2
32          1   5           0           21
33          2   1           1           21
34          1   3           0           21
```

I am attempting to get this back as my result:

```
shareId mode    shareLevel  targetId    targetItemId
26          1   5            0          2
33          2   1            1          21
```

*As a result I need the 'shareId' field.

*Group by TargetItemId so I only get back a single record for a given targetItemId

*BUT I need the record that has the highest mode value, so during the grouping, I want the field with the MAX(mode)

Here is what I tried but it isn't working:

```
select shareId FROM shares group by targetItemId having mode = MAX(mode)
```

It only returns:

```
shareId mode    shareLevel  targetId    targetItemId
26          1   5            0          2
```

So basically, how do I get the shareId for the each unique targetItemId, but I want the row for a given targetItemId that has the largest mode.  How do I do this?

Comment: How did you determine that you want record #26, rather than #33 or #34? From your description, it seems like they all satisfy your requirement equally.

Comment: Also -- you should indicate which SQL engine you're using (PostgreSQL? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?), because they all differ in their support for analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the ranking functions:

```
select shareId, mode, shareLevel, targetId, targetItemId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by targetItemId order by mode desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This assumes that you want only one row, even if the max of mode is repeated.  If you want all values, use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for whatever rdbms :

```
select shareId
from shares s
join (select max(mode) as mode,targetItemId from shares group by targetItemId) s_max
  on s.mode=s_max.mode 
 and s.targetItemId =s_max.targetItemId
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `MSSQL 2008+`, try this

```
WITH latestRecord
AS
(
    SELECT  shareId, [mode]    ,shareLevel  ,targetId   , targetItemId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY targetItemId ORDER BY [mode] DESC) AS RN
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  shareId, [mode]    ,shareLevel  ,targetId   , targetItemId
FROM    latestRecord
WHERE   RN = 1
```